# split row in to multiple rows of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which having columns start time and stop time.

for example

```
 Start time           Stop Time
 2014-01-01 23:43:00  2014-01-02 03:33:00
```

This i need to split in to 2014-01-01 23:43:00 - 2014-01-02 00:00:00 and 2014-01-02 00:00:00 - 2014-01-02 03:33:00 as two separate rows.

Comment: You want this to be done for all rows OR only for those rows in which start time and stop time are on different dates as in your above data?

Comment: i need it for all the rows!!

Comment: Last split is correct?You want to substract a day from Stop time?

Comment: @Mihai i have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the two column into individual rows and then use the `CASE` statement, like this:

```
select 
  CASE WHEN t.timetype=1 THEN mytime 
       WHEN t.timetype=2 THEN CONCAT(DATE(mytime), ' 00:00:00') 
  END as starttime,
  CASE WHEN t.timetype=1 THEN CONCAT(DATE_ADD(DATE(mytime), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' 00:00:00')
       WHEN t.timetype=2 THEN mytime 
  END as stoptime
from (
  select starttime as mytime, 1 as timetype from record
  union
  select stoptime as mytime, 2 as timetype from record
) t
```

**Working demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ef31/30

Here the table `t` will have 2 rows for each row of your `Records` table, one row will contain the `starttime` and the other row will contain `stoptime`. Each row of table `t` will also contain a `type`. Type 1 for `starttime` and type 2 for `stoptime`. Then the `CASE` statement will be used to generate your required data.

Comment: the above script you have shared will work only in the exampled which i have mentioned, there can be scenarios that the difference of start and stop date varies from 1 day, 2 days, 3 days .... so on ( assume max difference is of 10 days).

Comment: pls check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398982/split-single-row-into-multiple-rows-in-sql) i made my requirement more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  if (temp.row_n=1,t.start_time,t.stop_time) as time
from mytable t,
     (select 1 as row_n
      union
      select 2 as row_n) temp
```

Comment: Got below error after execution `ERROR:  function if(boolean, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
`

Comment: @dhanishjose you added mysql tag but obviously it's another db