# split single row into multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

In my table there are two fields start and stop which stores the start time and stop time respectively.

for example the Start time = 2014-01-01 23:43:00 and stop = 2014-01-03 03:33:00. This timestamp needs to brokendown to.

```
1=> 2014-01-01 23:43:00 - 2014-01-02 00:00:00, as date 2014-01-01
2=> 2014-01-02 00:00:01 - 2014-01-03 00:00:00, as date 2014-01-02 
3=> 2014-01-03 00:00:01 - 2014-01-03 03:33:00, as date 2014-01-03
```

as three different rows.

Here the problem is the difference in stop and start time varies say 1 day to 10 days.

To make it more complicate, in the above example i split the period on basis of date, this i need to split on basis of time ie. say split at time 02:30:00, so the spiting should e as follows.

```
1=> 2014-01-01 23:43:00 - 2014-01-02 02:30:00, as date 2014-01-01 
2=> 2014-01-02 02:30:01 - 2014-01-03 02:30:00, as date 2014-01-02 
3=> 2014-01-03 02:30:01 - 2014-01-03 02:30:00, as date 2014-01-03 
4=> 2014-01-03 02:30:01 - 2014-01-03 03:33:00, as date 2014-01-04
```

Once the above split has done, i need to count the rows grouped by date.

I'm using `PostgreSQL`.

Can anyone throw some light on this !!

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask for what end this request will suit - are you trying to write charge billing or something of the like?

Answer (score 2):

I think your "split by time" desired output sample is wrong and should 
in instead be this

```
1=> 2014-01-01 23:43:00 - 2014-01-02 02:30:00, as date 2014-01-01 
2=> 2014-01-02 02:30:01 - 2014-01-03 02:30:00, as date 2014-01-02 
3=> 2014-01-03 02:30:01 - 2014-01-03 03:33:00, as date 2014-01-03
```

If that is the case then this do it

```
select day, count(*)
from (
    select generate_series(
        (start_time - interval '2 hours 30 minutes')::date,
        stop_time,
        interval '1 day'
    )::date as day
    from t
) s
group by day
order by day
```

Comment: It is not wrong! if the time falls between `2014-01-03 02:30:01 and 2014-01-03 03:33:00`, then it should be tagged as date `2014-01-04`. The logic is simple, if the time falls between 2:30 to next day 2:30 it should be tagged as current day.

Comment: and to add things more complex, the time 2:30 can vary, it will be a input from user also the date time stored in table as epoch time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a collateral table - `period` and insert all possible periods in the table for let's say `from now() -10 years to now()+10 years`.

In case of days periods it should be all days of the 20 years.

After that you can select from the `period` table and JOIN your table with period extracting code

Answer (score 1):

You probably will need an additional table containing every date to join it to your base table.

If you had a table like `dates` containing values like:

```
date_col
2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-02 00:00:00
2014-01-03 00:00:00
...
```

Then you can do a query like

```
SELECT GREATEST(start_time, date_col), LEAST(end_time,date_col + interval 1 day) FROM base_table
JOIN dates ON date_col BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
```

SQL not tested but it shows tha idea.

Comment: I agree about the requirement of additional table; but no idea about how to fill this table by splitting the timestamp.